# How do I auto highlight specified text in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

For example this replaces all the words test with test.

```
:*?:test::test2
```

which works but I would like it to highlight that 'test2' given word.

Comment: This is close Send, +^{Left}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
 #NoEnv
 #SingleInstance Force

 ; Create a group of the windows you want to execute this or more hotstrings in the auto-execute section (top of the script):

; ahk_group Editors_Group
GroupAdd, Editors_Group, ahk_class Notepad
GroupAdd, Editors_Group, ahk_class Notepad2
GroupAdd, Editors_Group, ahk_class Notepad++
GroupAdd, Editors_Group, ahk_class WordPadClass
; ...

            RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===

; and use the #IfWinActive directive to make the hotstrings context-sensitive:

#IfWinActive, ahk_group Editors_Group

    :*?:test::
        Send {Text} test2
        Send {Blind}{Text}testing
        SendInput, ^+{Left}{Left}^+{Right}
    return

    
    ;  ...

#IfWinActive  ; turn off context sensitivity
```

See [GroupAdd](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupAdd.htm), [#IfWinActive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) and [Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) in the documentation.

Comment: How do this with the cursor at the end up the word?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: This works `:*?:following::
    Send {Blind}{Text}consecutively
 SendInput, ^+{Left}{Left}^+{Right}
return`

Comment: You can edit the answer and add your code, if it works.